# LogBack Message ILoggingEvent

Tags: java, logback

I have a class that extends LayoutBase. In the doLayout method, I add a key to my logging called MSG and the value is set to ILoggingEvent event.getMessage().

I'm seeing values added to my logging but they're not consistent; some logging messages and some exception stack traces.

Can anyone tell me where ILoggingEvent event.getMessage() gets its value from?

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to [Logback architecture](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html)

It mentions that each `log` will go through series of step

**Get Filter Chain Decision**
If it exists, the `TurboFilter` chain is invoked. Turbo filters can set a context-wide threshold, or filter out certain events based on information such as `Marker`, `Level`, `Logger`, `message`, or the `Throwable` that are associated with each logging request.

**Apply the selection rule**
At this step, logback **compares the effective level** of the logger with the level of the request. If the logging request is disabled according to this test, then logback will drop the request without further processing.

**Create a LoggingEvent object**
If the request survived the previous filters, logback will create a `LoggingEvent` object containing all the relevant parameters of the request

**Invoking appenders**
After the creation of a `LoggingEvent` object, logback will invoke the `doAppend()` methods of all the applicable **appenders**, that is, the appenders inherited from the logger context.

**Formatting the output**
It is the responsibility of the invoked appender to format the logging event. However, some (but not all) appenders `delegate the task of formatting` the logging event to a layout.

**Sending out the LoggingEvent**
After the logging event is fully formatted it is `sent to its destination` by each appender.

> I'm seeing values added to my logging but they're not consistent; some logging messages and some exception stack traces.

Now, coming to your query, it seems that you are receiving events which have exception information (`Throwable`) during the `formatting step`.

You can create a `CustomFilter` to filter out such events. All you have to do is extends `Filter<ILoggingEvent>`

```
public class DenyExceptionFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent iLoggingEvent) {
        final IThrowableProxy throwableProxy = iLoggingEvent.getThrowableProxy();
        if (throwableProxy != null && throwableProxy instanceof ThrowableProxy) 
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
    }
}
```

This can be much more powerful, can filter specific types of exception. You can take this as your homework :P

Then you can add this Custom Filter to your `appender` as

```
<appender name="APPENDER_NAME" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <filter class="com.stackoverflow.DenyExceptionFilter" />
</appender>
```

Of course, add your layout as well after the filter.